# Correct way to decorate an injectable angular service

Tags: angular, typescript

Source code:

```
export function MyServiceDecorator(parameters: { ObjectTypeID: string }) {
    return <T extends new(...args: any[]) => {}>(constructor: T) => {
        return class extends constructor {
            ObjectTypeID = parameters.ObjectTypeID;
        };
    };
}

@Injectable()
@MyServiceDecorator({ ObjectTypeID: 'test' })
class MyService {
    constructor(
        private anotherService: SomeService
    ) {}
}
```

It works, but Angular displays the following warning:

```
core.js:366 DEPRECATED: DI is instantiating a token "" that inherits its @Injectable decorator but does not provide one itself.
This will become an error in a future version of Angular. Please add @Injectable() to the "" class.
```

Can anyone explain the sense? And what is the correct way to decorate services?